# Sharing variables/objects across user controls

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have this class:

```
public class address
{
    public string address1;
    public string address2;
    public string city;
}
```

Now whenever a page load I fill these values based on the session userid in parent user control,

```
on_load of parent page
{
    connect to database;
    get the info
    address.address1 = "171, broadway";
}
```

now across the child user controls on this page I want to use these values...

`address.address1` and so on without hitting database again, this is a sample data actual data is long enough to use session.

What is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the Data in the current session and call it every time you need

This will help [Storing custom objects in Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644304/storing-custom-objects-in-sessions)

If Data is too big then just bind the data to all controls before "get the info"

Comment: Chris, I don't want to store data in sessions...wanted a better solution. I know sessions but data is too big as i mentioned above that was just a sample data

Comment: Why do you want to keep a big object data in memory??

Answer (score 0):

Add a property called Address to each `UserControl` that should have access to this data. Then in the parent `UserControl`, set this property for each control.