# Asp.Net Core - quick access local cache/storage

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I'm looking for a quick read/write method to store data but only for the session long. I will be accessing the data every second from different threads. But I could end up having separate file/cache for every thread. 
I was thinking about local json file, as the data will be in this format. Is this good approach or maybe there is better method to do it? The read/write operations will only be on back end of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a session variable.

See this SO posting for an example: [Storing custom objects in Sessions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644304/storing-custom-objects-in-sessions)